# put <a> element in document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do

```
document.write("<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>");
```

but nothing shows up. Can I not use  in document.write? Other HTML elements work fine, like  and

, but nothing from this one? Is there a better way to do links? I have also tried

```
[a link](http://www.example.com/)
```

but still nothing.

Comment: One, try to avoid [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) and, second: "*I have also tried...*" - you tried to use Markdown in your project? Why did you think that would work?

Comment: Don't post code here which generates console errors. Track them down yourself first. If you don't know what the console is, stop everything you're doing and learn what it is and how to use it.

Comment: The answers given will fix your immediate problem, but `document.write()` is poor practice for a number of reasons.  Do a search on `innerHTML`.  Although `innerHTML` is not part of the W3C standards and has some quirks of its own, it's better than `document.write()`.

Comment: Also, learn basic posting format. If you include tags such as `<h>` or `<p>` in your post, but do not surround them with back-ticks, then they will not appear in your post as displayed, most likely making it incomprehensible. If you had bothered to actually look at your post after posting, you would have seen this. I hope you take more care with your code than you do with your SO posts.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write()`, create an `anchor` element instead.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.google.com'
var text = document.createTextNode('Visit Google');
a.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes inside, replace them:
`document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Visit Google</a>");`

or

`document.write('<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>');`

or escape them like in the post below:

`document.write("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Visit Google</a>");`